# ODOO - Form View with many models

Tags: odoo

I have a form view with 3 pages in the notebook. I need to have 3 models in the same form, but the ODOO only allows one. Is there any way around this?

Edit:
I need a structure similar to this:

[image]

Because I need something like this:

[image]

I made a simple example that could put it all together on the same model, but the reality is more complex and needs to be on each page of the notebook a different model. In other words, I need to have the same form, 4 different models.

Best regards

Comment: No it isnt, why you need it?

Comment: Because, they are very differents, and I don't want to put related fields or merge all fields in one model.

Comment: can you give us more details?

Comment: Hi, @DachiDarchiashvili, I edit my question. Hope that would be explicit.

Comment: you could create one model which has a one2many field to the other 3 models